# GNOME ignores natural scrolling setting

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3

I just updated to GNOME 3.22.1 on Arch Linux. When I tried to scroll, I noticed that it ignores the setting of natural scrolling. I'm stuck with natural scrolling (you move your fingers down and the page goes up) but I don't want to. I tried both settings in the `Mouse & Touchpad` settings.

The currently installed version of `xorg-server` is on 1.18.4 and was installed three months ago. My laptop is a Thinkpad T440s.

Comment: Can't check this (as I'm not on my laptop right now) but keep in mind 3.22 defaults to `wayland` session. Log out and log back in choosing X session when at GDM login screen and see if it works...

Comment: @don_crissti thanks. that was the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [don-crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti)'s comment:

> (GNOME) 3.22 defaults to a Wayland session. Log out and log back in choosing X session when at GDM login screen and see if it works.